# Is text in Javascript HMTL scripts taken into account in Google (or other) indexes?

Tags: google, html, javascript, search-engine-indexing

I have a HTML page where I update the content of a div to display some introduction text when displaying the page. It is hard for me to create copies of this page for all possibilities and move the text as static content correspondingly.

When I have a Javascript, something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setIntroduction("This is my introduction text etc... etc...");
    </script>
```

Does Google (or other index tool) take into account the `This is my introduction text etc... etc...` text, since it appears in the page? Or is it ignored?

Comment: i'm a bit late to the party...but sounds like a great use for noscript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does parse and execute some JavaScript. How far those capabilities go is unknown but is definitely limited. It is widely assumed that basic JavaScript such as in your example is basic enough for them to parse and understand so any content generated by that HTML would be recognized and factored into your page's rankings.